# How to print first word of first line and last word of last line in unix in a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Suppose there is a file file1.c It has 100 lines . I need to print first word and last word of that file.

Comment: ```awk``` can be awkward, for a 'budget' approach you may want to check ```head```, ```tail``` and ```cut``` commands.

Comment: @PS. Please don't answer in comments. This bypasses quality control because people can't both up and **down** vote comments.

Comment: @CJDennis understood.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show how you have tried to solve the problem so far so you can be guided. Please also take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: true many linux systems might not have awk installed

Answer (score 4):

first word: `head -1 file1.c | cut -d" " -f 1`

last word: `tail -1 file1.c | rev | cut -d" " -f 1 | rev`

`head -1` print first line

`-d` stands for delimeter in this case `" "` (space)

`-f 1` first field

`tail -1` print last line

`rev` reverse the input - in this case first `rev` cause that line is "mirrored" so last field is now first, so we can `cut` it. Second `rev` reverse/mirror back the desired field so its readable

Comment: Although this answer is valid, explaining it would greatly improve it's quality.  Explain the `rev` usage.

Comment: rev is basicaly used to reverse a line .  he is getting the last line with tail . then he is reversing the line with rev. then by using cut he is getting the first word of the reversed line

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1} END{print $NF}' file1.c
```

`NR==1` : means, line number should be 1. 
`END{}`: This block will get executed at the last line of the file. 
`$1` : First column 
`$NF`: last column. Hope it helps.

Comment: `NR` - *number of the current record* (which equate to the line number `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Translate the file to one line and remove everything between the first and last space:

```
tr -d "\n" < file1.c| sed 's/ .* / /'
```

When you file starts or ends with a space, this won't work.
You can fix that with the more complicated

```
tr -d "\n" < file1.c| sed -r 's/[ ]*([^ ]+).*([^ ]+)/\1 \2/'
```